# How to get the original size of an image -Jquery

Tags: jquery, height, width

## **SOLVED**: Syntax-Error

The following code works:

```
var image = {width:0,height:0};
var imageObject = new Image();
function getImageSize(id) {
    imageObject.src = id.attr("src");
    image.width = imageObject.width;
    image.height = imageObject.height;
}
```

---

## **Original Question**

I want to get the original width and height of an image and tried different code to achieve it. My function triggers on click event and all images are resized to 400x300.

I tried to resize the Image to its original size by using `auto`:

```
var image = {width:0,heigth:0};
function getImageSize(id) {
    id.css({
        'width': 'auto',
        'heigth': 'auto'
    });
    image.width = id.attr('width');
    image.heigth = id.attr('heigth');
}
```

Attaching `auto` didn't change the size of the image.

`alert(id.attr('width'));` always returns 'undefined'. so it doesn't work

```
var image = {width:0,heigth:0};
var imageObject = new Image();
function getImageSize(id) {
    imageObject.src = id.attr("src");
    image.width = imageObject.width;
    image.heigth = imageObject.heigth;
}
```

`alert(image.width);` works perfectly.

`alert(image.heigth);` returns undefined.

Using `imageObject.naturalWidth` works as the one above - the width is given correctly but the heigth is undefined.

I read that you have to append the new image object, but when I use `imageObject.appendTo('body');` I can't even click the image.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Once you change the image size, auto will not bring it back again. As for getting the size of the image, it has to be loaded first.

Comment: `image.heigth` syntax error: "height"

Comment: oh, i wrote it wrong alot of times,
changing syntax solved it

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple contained example of replacing an image with one that has its original sizes after having been altered.

```
<img src="http://www.finesttreeserviceaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/tree2.gif" id="bar" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myImg = document.getElementById("bar");
    myImg.setAttribute("style", "width:400px;height:300px;");
    function resetBar() {
        var newImg = new Image();
        var oldImage = document.getElementById("bar");
        newImg.src = oldImage.src;
        oldImage.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg, oldImage);
    }
    setTimeout("resetBar();", 2000);
</script>
```

An alternative would be to remove the style that was applied:

```
myImg.removeAttribute("style");
```